# OpenCV Object Detection Memory Issue

Tags: c, opencv, memory-management

The code I wrote below is objection detection using size-invariant template matching. This technique was detailed in the following site: https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&q=http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/&source=gmail&ust=1489552541603000&usg=AFQjCNHSfgL_RTy-o5SMyCmWELFbsfOOTw

The function works fine. However, when I am running too many iterations in the while loop, OpenCV Error: Insufficient Memory will occur.
I can't seem to figure out why I'm running into this error as I'm releasing the the matrix data that I'm creating in cvCreateMat in every iteration. The memory error occurs after running the loop several times and in the function cvMatchTemplate. Am I missing another source of error? I am writing this code in C on the LCDK.

Function:

```
double minVal = 0.0;
double maxVal = 0.0 ;
CvPoint minLoc;
CvPoint maxLoc;

double ratio = 1.0;

CvMat* mask2 = NULL;

//for containing the maximum values

CvMat* resized_source;
CvMat* result; //result stored for every shapes

while (1){
    // All templates are sized around the same
    if(width_curr <= template->cols || height_curr <= template->rows)
        break;

    resized_source = cvCreateMat(height_curr,width_curr,CV_8UC1);
    cvResize(source_close_edge_dist_8,resized_source,CV_INTER_LINEAR);

    result = cvCreateMat((resized_source->rows)-(template->rows)+1, (resized_source->cols)-(template->cols)+1, CV_32FC1);

    cvMatchTemplate(resized_source, template, result, CV_TM_CCOEFF);

    //Detecting several objects
    cvMinMaxLoc(result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, mask2);

    *(max_all+*size) = maxVal;
    (max_all_point+*size)->x = maxLoc.x;
    (max_all_point+*size)->y = maxLoc.y;
    *(max_all_ratio+*size) = sqrt(ratio);
    *size = *size + 1;

    // move on to next resizing
    ratio -= 0.04;
    width_curr = sqrt(ratio)*width;
    height_curr = sqrt(ratio)*height;
    minVal = 0.0;
    maxVal =0.0 ;

    cvReleaseData(resized_source);
    cvReleaseMat(&resized_source);
    cvReleaseData(result);
    cvReleaseMat(&result);
}
```